# react-bootstrap Navbar not rendering properly in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 4 with reactjs. Using react-bootstrap module, trying to render the Navbar , but somehow , it is not rendering properly. 
i am using bootstrap 4 syntax in the code but not sure whether any module/lib is using any bootstrap syntax 3

**here is the code (App.js) :**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Components/HeaderComponents/header';
import Footer from './Components/FooterComponents/footer';
import Homepage from './Components/pages/homePage';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import CustNavbar from './Components/pages/navbar';
import About from './Components/pages/About';

import News from './Components/pages/News';

import ReactBootstrap, { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, Jumbotron, Container, Row, Column, Image, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './Assets/css/default.min.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <Router>
      <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/news" component={News} />
      </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

**and the navbar.js :**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactBootstrap, { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class CustNavbar extends Component {
render() {
  return (

<Navbar default collapseOnSelect>
<Navbar.Header>
<Navbar.Brand>
  <Link to="/">CodeLife</Link>
</Navbar.Brand>
<Navbar.Toggle />
  </Navbar.Header>
  <Navbar.Collapse>
<Nav pullRight>
<NavItem eventKey={1} componentClass={Link} to="/">
Home
</NavItem>

<NavItem eventKey={2} componentClass={Link} to="/about">
About
</NavItem>
<NavItem eventKey={3} componentClass={Link} to="/news">
News
</NavItem>
</Nav>

</Navbar.Collapse>

</Navbar>

)
}
}

export default CustNavbar;
```

**what is happening**

now the issue, there is no any compilation error , but somehow , Navigation bar is not rendering properly. Not sure whether the issue with version syntax or the implementation itself. please suggest

**what is expected**

Navigation bar should appear in the homepage before Grid/container

**EDIT 1:** 
I have modified the code as suggested . please below :

**App.js**

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Components/HeaderComponents/header';
import Footer from './Components/FooterComponents/footer';
import Homepage from './Components/pages/homePage';
import CorporateTraining from './Components/pages/corporateTraining';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import CustNavbar from './Components/pages/navbar';
import About from './Components/pages/About';

import News from './Components/pages/News';

import ReactBootstrap, { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, Jumbotron, Container, Row, Column, Image, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './Assets/css/default.min.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <Fragment>
    <Navbar />
      <div className="App">
      <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/news" component={News} />

      </Router>
      </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure as its too unclear. But try moving your navbar on top of router as i assume that className App have styling in them. Let me know

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react';
        ...

        return (
             <Fragment>
                  <Navbar />
                  <div className="App">
                    <Router>
                    <Switch>
                      <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
                      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                      <Route path="/news" component={News} />
                    </Switch
                    </Router>
                  </div>
          </Fragment>
    )
```

Don't forget to add **Fragment**

Comment: Thanks. I added as you instructed but no change .. still same issue. see above the edit. please suggest

Comment: further , i did not get when you say , ClassName App will have styling in them .. what is that ?

Comment: Hi sorry, for the late reply. the question is kinda confusing. I added <Switch> above which should toggle components(read here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch). With regards to "className App", I assume you had styling in them that could lead to your styling problem.

Comment: Thanks. I imported the Switch module and added the <Switch> tag, still the same issue. With regards to "className App", i do not have any styling as such. there is no any file called App.css in my project. could you please tell me which styling i have to import ? This may be a issue with something due to missing 'css' file ? please suggest

Comment: I don't know exactly the issue as its too vague. Can you reproduce it in a sandbox or link to the repo?